# Установить дефолтное значение если не найден property

Tags: java, spring

В app.xml есть такое SpEL выражение:

```
#{'${app.prop}'?:'default'}
```

Если `app.prop` найден в доступных `.properties` файлах, то будет установлено оно, а иначе бросается `exception` на этапе компиляции, и *элвис* оператор не работает. Как сделать так, чтобы он работал?
Или возможно иначе: как получить `reference` на `bean`, ответственный за предоставление `property` в `SpEL` выражении?

Comment: "${app.prop:default}" ?

Comment: Ага, оно, спасибо).